# Observable compatibility without RXJS

Tags: rxjs

Does RXJS architecture allow implementation of a compatible Observable without including RXJS library? And if it does, is there any documentation/reference/examples for that?

I want to bring RXJS compatibility into some of my libraries, without bringing in the entire RXJS as a dependency. I have some custom events that I want to extend as Observable-compatible, so they can optionally work with a wide variety of RXJS versions, i.e. anywhere between v5 and v7+

Comment: To my knowledge, no. But if you expose a traditional callback pattern, RxJs has tools to create observables from those.

Comment: RxJS doesn't have any additional dependencies and if you import properly you should be able to use no more than you need. It's all tree-shakable etc. I'm not sure how much sense it makes to roll out your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and I don't think there's any official documentation regarding this topic.

I guess you're refering to this proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable that should define some common groud for all Observable implementations. I've seen the TC39 proposal mentioned many times in RxJS issue tracker and commits aligning RxJS with the proposal. See this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/search?q=tc39&type=issues.

However, I've never seen anyone switching from one Observable implementation to another, though I believe it should be possible(?).